# Python -- what is NOT in 2.7 that IS in 3.1? So many things have been back-ported, what is NOT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've been following the saga of Python 3.x and have watched the 3.x features gradually getting back-ported to the 2.x line.

Most of the libraries I use haven't been ported and some (e.g. Twisted) seem covertly or overtly hostile to 3.x to varying degrees.  At any rate, there has been very little movement towards compatible versions of many of them.  Expecially the larger ones.

So, my question is, with all the features that have been backported, what is still available in 3.x that's NOT been back-ported?  It's pretty easy to find what *has* been backported, but not *what's left*.

Right now, porting to 3.x just seems like all pain, and I can't see the gain; maybe an "Only in 3.x" list would let me see the light...

Thanks,

Stu

Comment: Do you count those features imported by `from __future__ import ???`?

Comment: Sounds like you really want to know why you should port to Python3. That has been answered many times already.

Comment: No, I'm actually trying to find out what is in Python 3 that hasn't been back-ported.

Comment: Implementing backported features (probably the most interesting ones) is not necessarily less painful than outright migration to Python 3: for example from __future__ import unicode_literals will wreak havoc in many Python 2 applications.

Answer (score 6):

The most important thing is probably unicode throughout. So there is no need anymore to fiddle around with str/unicode. This sounds small but has huge (positive) implications when you think of OS interaction - for example everyone has to try hard to give you 'usable' strings instead of 'a binary thing that might be an error message'.

There's also a lot of stuff in the interpreter itself that was improved. One example is the global interpreter lock (GIL) which did not vanish but it way better in py3k: [presentation+slides](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1101/mindblowing-python-gil)

Comment: 3.3 has an improved unicode implementation.  There are other unicode improvements and bugfixes only in current 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

Speed might be a feature worth mentioning.

The speed imporovements of project "Unladen Swallow" have been approved to be merged into Python. But as far as I know only to Python 3. See [PEP 3146](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3146/) for details.

Comment: AFAIK, US is a non-starter at this point due to severe memory requirements and long startup times, though I'm sure that will be worked out (perhaps with pre-profiling as many have suggested).

Comment: If by "non-starter" you mean, "pre-alpha" then, yes.  Unladen Swallow is approved to be integrated with CPython, and there's no significant barriers to that happening, once the relevant work gets done.

Comment: The developer community doesn't seem to have a lot of enthusiasm to follow-through on Unladen Swallow for Python 3. Perhaps they were relying on Google's support of that work, but from the mailing list it seems Google has moved those developers onto other work that is higher-priority for Google.

Comment: The 'speed improvements' were more hypothetical than real and the project is dead. Pypy has been more successful.